# Is there a way in HTML (or ColdFusion) to have a radio button trigger a hyperlink without having to submit a form?

Tags: html, coldfusion

I want to have a pair of radio buttons sitting over an HTML table so that whenever the rb is clicked it will cause the table to rebuild (rebuild the page) by submitting a different URL variable. Is there a way to do this without having to build a form and click a submit button? I'm pretty new to this stuff so please keep any answers basic and/or show samples of code. Thanks!

Comment: You can but it's not necessarily a good idea.  You will be processing actions that don't necessarily reflect the explicit intent of the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Html is a Markup Language it will not do the logic for you. that way javascript is there .

```
<input id="gotogoogle" type="radio" name="name" value="google" checked>
<script>
    var radiob = document.getElementById("gotogoogle");

    radiob.addEventListener("change", function() {
        if(radiob.value == "google")
        {
            document.location = "http:\\www.gooogle.com"
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Naqib, I'm trying to use your suggestion to work on my page. I can't quite get it working.Is there a way I can show you the code I'm using so you can see where the error is?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, you can use Javascript event binding to help you achieve this. This will get you started. This adds an event binding so when you "change" or click the radio buttons, it can fire an event off.

From here you'd need to research how to rebuild the table data in JS if you don't already know.

```
$("input[@name='nameofinput']").change(function(){
    // Do something interesting here
});
```